# How to select first empty value option in a select menu?

Tags: html, html-select

The following always preselects the last option, even when I set the `selected` attribute, but I like the first option to be preselected.

```
<select name="filter">
    <option value="" selected>Make a choice</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="">all</option>
</select>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: your coding is correct.  I think there is a cache problem.  Press ctrl+F5 for refresh with cache.

Comment: This should be correct in most browsers. Which browser are you using? Did you force the page reload to confirm that it is really not working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<select name="filter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Make a choice</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="">all</option>
</select>
```

If my code modification does not work. Check this article and make sure it's not something you're running in to http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/12/16/option-selectedselected-not-working/

Answer (score 0):

the correct implementation is:

```
<option value="1" selected>1</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
```